# Can you apply a formula to the count filter of a pivot table? Trying to find duplicates in a large dataset

Tags: excel, duplicates, pivot-table

I have a huge dataset of brands, stores and devices. A store can have multiple brands. There are no duplicate device numbers. I need to figure out for each brand (Pop, Rock, etc.), how many stores have duplicate brands (e.g, Store 110 in the table below has two pop brand devices).

[image: Example Table]

I have figured it out on this simple example dataset using pivot tables. However, I need to apply this to a huge dataset with over 100 brands and thousands of stores. Is there a way to automate the process so I can figure out for each brand, how many duplicate stores there are?

[[image: Here is the pivot table][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uher1.png)

Is there a way for me to apply a field that returns a value if the count of stores is over 1? Then can I summarize this by brand?

Comment: Don't know what you expect those dark, impossible to read images to do. Text tables would be much better, as they can be copied and pasted to use as test data when trying to come up with an answer.  See Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which applies to sample data as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just add in a column to tell you if the brand is a duplicate for that store? You can then put the result in a pivot table or just filter it to find your answer

`=countifs(C:C,C2,A:A,A2)>1`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!! It was for my boyfriend's work and he just started so he is super grateful :) Thank you Hooded One!!!!!